# Which Anisotropic Diffusion Method is Best for Denoising Now?

Tags: image-processing, denoising, anisotropic-diffusion

The best standard may be varying from PSNR to human's visual feeling. Any one is OK.

I have tested J.Weickert's tensor diffusion and P&M's, they all can't satisfy me.

Is there any anisotropic diffusion method now is best for denoising, especially in tensor diffusion, others like the KAD, MAD and so on is ok as well.

Thanks for reading~

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think "[Fast Anisotropic Smoothing of Multi-Valued Images using Curvature Preserving PDE’s](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00315835/)" by David Tschumperlé is really good.

I started implementing it using MATLAB once, yet I didn't finish.
If you do implement it, it will be great if you updated us.

#### Update

Have a look on my implementation at [Fast Anisotropic Curvature Preserving Smoothing](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/FastAnisotropicCurvaturePreservingSmoothing).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am an undergraduate, and I find Tschumerle's paper seems a little difficult to me especially in implementing it. My email is jim2429212@gmail.com , would you like to send me the code ? If I can make some improvement, I promise to inform you and share the code.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/JarnoRalli/PDE-based-image-processing/issues/1